# Opening links in TFS in internal webbrowser in Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server are highly integrated. The only thing that use another application is when clicking on hyperlinks, such as the Project Portal and Web Access, which opens the link in the default webbrowser.

I would like to override this behavior and open these links in a tab in the internal webbrowser inside Visual Studio.

Is it possible change an option to make Visual Studio open TFS links in the internal webbrowser instead of opening them in the default webbrowser?

Comment: @gnat: I found the question to be a "programmer" question, and not a "programming" question. Didn't read the following in the FAQ: "and it (http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is not about: implementation issues or programming tools (ask on Stack Overflow instead)"